# Starting rails before rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way within an RSpec tests, by convention or code, to have rails start before tests run? I'm trying to setup a testing framework for selenium tests that use chrome, and now I'm only hindered by my lack of a running server.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'The first tab' do
  before(:each) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  end

  it 'Shows the list' do
    @driver.navigate.to 'index.html'
  end
end
```

I'm new to RSpec, so I'm not sure how I would create a suite of tests that all ran while a rails server was running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just run `rails server` and kill the process went tests complete.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using [Capybara](http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to test this stuff instead. It uses selenium-webdriver internally to provide JavaScript testing support.

with Capybara, you put this test in either the `spec/integration` or `spec/requests` folder and write it like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'The first tab' do
  it "shows the list", :js => true do
    visit list_path
  end
end
```

By putting `:js => true` after the example's name Capybara will know to run this as a JavaScript test.

Comment: The documentation for direct use of the webdriver is good; capybara is lacking. I was using this at first and realized I didn't need capybara so long as I could start a server to run tests against.

Comment: +1 from me. -1 shouldn't be for answers one doesn't agree with but for answers that are not relevant/helpful, which I don't believe is the case here.

Comment: Also, look into `spork` which will initialize your Rails environment only once.

Comment: Also, test your user-facing stuff with Cucumber, not RSpec.

Comment: @Marnen: it doesn't matter what you test it with. Both are fine tools for testing user-facing things.

Comment: Ryan: No. RSpec is best suited for application logic. Cucumber is designed as a UI/UX testing tool, and works far better than RSpec in that niche. I've used RSpec for user-facing tests, and "fine" is not a word I'd use for the result, unless followed by "mess". :)

Comment: This does not get me closer to using rspec with a rails instance, unless I take on the entire testing framework and then don't use it. At all. Capybara's documentation is pretty terrible, so I'm not going to use it.

Comment: FWIW I prefer RSpec+Capybara to Cucumber for UI testing. To each his own.

Comment: I'll take a look at cucumber. I just really want to use the native selenium ruby bindings. I don't actually *have* a rails application; I'm using gradle to build my HTML5 app into `/public/` so I can run selenium with chrome. HTML tests would almost do, but then I can't run in chrome, and that means I can't test anything.

Cucumber looks interesting, and hey look, docs.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: Cucumber is beautiful for running and managing selenium tests driven with the raw driver. It's really working a lot better and faster than RSpec by itself, and the tests are cleaner and more descriptive. Love it!

Comment: @zetetic "To each his own" is not usually a phrase that belongs in a software developer's vocabulary, I think. In a field where facts are demonstrable, if we can't justify our practices with those facts, then we should reevaluate our practices.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser *In a field where facts are demonstrable*--what sort of facts do you mean? Software quality? Speed of development? Developer happiness? I'd argue it's not so easy to boil down the entire software development process and its attendant concerns quite so easily. As to *why* I prefer RSpec/Capybara to Cucumber, it's simply that I don't see that Cucumber adds anything compelling enough for me to abandon a tool I already know and learn another one. That said, you may disagree, So, to each his own :)

Comment: @zetetic "what sort of facts do you mean?" The facts of what gets tested by what sort of tests. "abandon a tool I already know and learn another one" Nothing is abandoned. Cucumber works *along with* RSpec and Capybara, and provides a level of abstraction that RSpec and Capybara simply *cannot* achieve (easily, at least) without it. "to each his own" No. If you're not using Cucumber for your user-facing tests, you're doing it wrong: you're testing implementation when behavior is what needs to be tested. This is not a matter of taste.

Comment: `visit login_page; click 'submit';` How is that testing implementation?

Comment: @zetetic That's not testing anything, actually; it's simply automating Capybara's browser robot. It's the setup phase, not the assertion phase.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser OK, how about `expect(page).to have_content 'Am I testing implementation?'`

Comment: @zetetic That's fine as far as it goes. The problems come when you do more complex things: Gherkin provides a level of abstraction that helps keep you focused on what the user sees, not how that is implemented. If you're writing in Ruby rather than Gherkin, then the temptation is always there to drop down to a lower level of abstraction and start thinking like a programmer when you should be thinking like a UI tester. Every time I have seen user-facing functionality tested without Cucumber, the temptation has at some point been succumbed to, which means the wrong things are getting tested.